# Why is my API post request working on Postman but not on Python?

Tags: python, json, api, post, postman

I have been trying to send a POST request via Python but I keep getting error responses from the server. Yet when I test it on Postman it works properly and I get the required response.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be happening?

Python code:

```
import requests
import json

def post():
    pload = {
    "params": {
        "db": dbname,
        "login": username,
        "password": password
    }
}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post('http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/YYY/YYYYY',headers=headers,json = pload)
    return(r.text)

def post2():
    pload = {"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "call","params": {"args": [[["user_id","=",2]],["attendance_state","name"]],"model": "hr.employee","method": "search_read","kwargs": {}},"id": 73828292}  
    r = requests.post('http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/XXX/XXXXX',headers=headers,json = pload)
    return(r.text)

print(post())
print(post2())
```

Python output:

```
PS C:\Users\App> python post.py
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "result": {"session_id": "673d8c43496b9ceeecc4ac31602f4cd0b6d6339a", "uid": 2, "is_system": true, "is_admin": true, "user_context": {"lang": "en_US", "tz": "Asia/Kolkata", "uid": 2}, "db": dbname, "server_version": xxxxxxx, "server_version_info": [xx, x, x, "final", x, ""], "name": xxxx, "username": username, "partner_display_name": xxxx, "company_id": 1, "partner_id": 3, "user_companies": false, "currencies": {"1": {"symbol": "\u20ac", "position": "after", "digits": [69, 2]}, "20": {"symbol": "\u20b9", "position": "after", "digits": [69, 2]}, "2": {"symbol": "$", "position": "before", "digits": [69, 2]}}, "web.base.url": "http://34.87.62.211", "show_effect": "True", "max_time_between_keys_in_ms": 55, "web_tours": [], "odoobot_initialized": true}}
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 49458607, "error": {"code": 404, "message": "404: Not Found", "data": {"name": "werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound", "debug": "Traceback (most 
recent call last):\n  File \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 656, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 314, in _handle_exception\n    
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n  File \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 87, in reraise\n    raise value\n  File \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 1460, in _dispatch_nodb\n    func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()\n  File \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 1563, in match\n    raise NotFound()\nwerkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404: Not Found\n", "message": "404: Not Found", "arguments": [], "exception_type": "internal_error"}, "http_status": 404}}
```

Comment: Show json request from Postman and dictionary `pload` (it is not clear from your code what works and what does not).

Comment: code 404 means you are posting to URL that does not exist

Comment: @Evg have shown pload now

Comment: The `pload` content must be in jsonrpc format (the format from a running Postman query must be repeated completely).

Comment: For example: pload = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "some_method",
    "params": {
     "db": dbname,
        "login": username,
        "password": password
    },
    "id": 1
}

Comment: The first pload in post() method works properly. It is giving the proper response without requiring to give jsonrpc and so on..

Comment: It's the second post2() method that is giving the error on python. And as you can see in the pload I have mentioned jsonrpc, method  so on..

Comment: in Postman there is function to generate Python code (in content menu - right button mouse).

Comment: BTW: when you use `json=data` then it automatically add header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and you don't have to add it manually.

Comment: BTW: in Postman and Python you can send POST to https://httbin.org/post and it sends back JSON with all received data and headers - and then you can compare data send by Postman with data send by Python. Eventually you can use local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and send all from Postman and Python using this proxy server - and then you can observer all data in proxy servers and compare them.